# apache flink 0.10 how to get the first occurence of a composite key from an unbounded input dataStream?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am a newbie with apache flink. I have an unbound data stream in my input (fed into flink 0.10 via kakfa).

I want to get the 1st occurence of each primary key (the primary key is the contract_num and the event_dt). 
These "duplicates" occur nearly immediately after each other.
The source system cannot filter this for me, so flink has to do it.

Here is my input data:

```
contract_num, event_dt, attr 
A1, 2016-02-24 10:25:08, X
A1, 2016-02-24 10:25:08, Y
A1, 2016-02-24 10:25:09, Z
A2, 2016-02-24 10:25:10, C
```

Here is the output data I want:

```
A1, 2016-02-24 10:25:08, X
A1, 2016-02-24 10:25:09, Z
A2, 2016-02-24 10:25:10, C
```

Note the 2nd row has been removed as the key combination of A001 and '2016-02-24 10:25:08' already occurred in the 1st row.

How can I do this with flink 0.10?

I was thinking about using `keyBy(0,1)` but after that I don't know what to do!

(I used joda-time and org.flinkspector to setup these tests).

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    DateTime threeSecondsAgo = (new DateTime()).minusSeconds(3);
    DateTime twoSecondsAgo = (new DateTime()).minusSeconds(2);
    DateTime oneSecondsAgo = (new DateTime()).minusSeconds(2);

    DataStream<Tuple3<String, Date, String>> testStream =
            createTimedTestStreamWith(
                    Tuple3.of("A1", threeSecondsAgo.toDate(), "X"))
            .emit(Tuple3.of("A1", threeSecondsAgo.toDate(), "Y"), after(0, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS))
            .emit(Tuple3.of("A1", twoSecondsAgo.toDate(), "Z"), after(0, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS))
            .emit(Tuple3.of("A2", oneSecondsAgo.toDate(), "C"), after(0, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS))
            .close();
    
    testStream.keyBy(0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Filtering duplicates over an infinite stream will eventually fail if your key space is larger than your available storage space. The reason is that you have to store the already seen keys somewhere to filter out the duplicates. Thus, it would be good to define a time window after which you can purge the current set of seen keys.

If you're aware of this problem but want to try it anyway, you can do it by applying a stateful `flatMap` operation after the `keyBy` call. The stateful mapper uses Flink's state abstraction to store whether it has already seen an element with this key or not. That way, you will also benefit from Flink's fault tolerance mechanism because your state will be automatically checkpointed.

A Flink program doing your job could look like

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    DataStream<Tuple3<String, Date, String>> input = env.fromElements(Tuple3.of("foo", new Date(1000), "bar"), Tuple3.of("foo", new Date(1000), "foobar"));

    input.keyBy(0, 1).flatMap(new DuplicateFilter()).print();

    env.execute("Test");
}
```

where the implementation of `DuplicateFilter` depends on the version of Flink.

#### Version >= 1.0 implementation

```java
public static class DuplicateFilter extends RichFlatMapFunction<Tuple3<String, Date, String>, Tuple3<String, Date, String>> {

    static final ValueStateDescriptor<Boolean> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("seen", Boolean.class, false);
    private ValueState<Boolean> operatorState;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration configuration) {
        operatorState = this.getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap(Tuple3<String, Date, String> value, Collector<Tuple3<String, Date, String>> out) throws Exception {
        if (!operatorState.value()) {
            // we haven't seen the element yet
            out.collect(value);
            // set operator state to true so that we don't emit elements with this key again
            operatorState.update(true);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Version 0.10 implementation

```java
public static class DuplicateFilter extends RichFlatMapFunction<Tuple3<String, Date, String>, Tuple3<String, Date, String>> {

    private OperatorState<Boolean> operatorState;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration configuration) {
        operatorState = this.getRuntimeContext().getKeyValueState("seen", Boolean.class, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap(Tuple3<String, Date, String> value, Collector<Tuple3<String, Date, String>> out) throws Exception {
        if (!operatorState.value()) {
            // we haven't seen the element yet
            out.collect(value);
            operatorState.update(true);
        }
    }
}
```

### Update: Using a tumbling time window

```java
input.keyBy(0, 1).timeWindow(Time.seconds(1)).apply(new WindowFunction<Iterable<Tuple3<String,Date,String>>, Tuple3<String, Date, String>, Tuple, TimeWindow>() {
    @Override
    public void apply(Tuple tuple, TimeWindow window, Iterable<Tuple3<String, Date, String>> input, Collector<Tuple3<String, Date, String>> out) throws Exception {
        out.collect(input.iterator().next());
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi TIll, thanks alot for your answer! is there a way of doing this with flink 0.10? I am a bit nervous about using 1-0-snapshot as its not a stable release and i am a coward!

Comment: Sure, I will post the 0.10 version in a minute. Btw: we're about to release the version 1.0 in one or two weeks so that you could upgrade then :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer and added an implementation for version 0.10.

Comment: Thanks alot Till - great job!!!! Another question, i know that the duplicates come within 1 second of each other (machine time). how can i tell flink to discard entries after 1 second?

Comment: You could use a tumbling time window of 1 second length. This will collect all elements which arrive in the 1 second interval for each key. After the time interval has passed, the window is triggered and a `WindowFunction` is applied. There you can simply emit the first element. This is easy to implement, but has the disadvantage that you introduce a latency of 1 second to your elements (because you wait until your window is completed before you emit elements).

Comment: Super Till, kannst du mir bitte auch hier ein beispiel geben wie man es schreibt? would it look like this?   input.keyBy(0, 1).timeWindow(Time.seconds(1), Time.seconds(1)).flatMap(new DuplicateFilter())

Comment: I've extended my answer to include the time window solution as well.

Comment: Its not working yet - what do i need to change? here is the code:
     input.keyBy(0, 1).timeWindow(Time.seconds(1)).apply(new WindowFunction<
       Tuple3<String,Date,String>, 
       Tuple3<String,Date,String>, 
       Tuple, 
       TimeWindow>() {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     @Override
     public void apply(Tuple key, TimeWindow window, Iterable<Tuple3<String, Date, String>> values,
       Collector<Tuple3<String, Date, String>> out) throws Exception {
      out.collect(values.iterator().next());
     }      
     }).flatMap(new DuplicateFilter()).print();

Comment: here is the exception (flink 0.10): 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The function or operator is not executed on a KeyedStream and can hence not access the key/value state
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.createKeyValueState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:289)
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.createKeyValueState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:253)
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamingRuntimeContext.getKeyValueState(StreamingRuntimeContext.java:169)
 at ...

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to do this that I happen to have just written.  It has the disadvantage that it's a bit more custom code since it doesn't use the built-in Flink windowing functions but it doesn't have the latency penalty that Till mentioned.  Full example on [GitHub](https://github.com/jgrier/FilteringExample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dataartisans/filters/DedupeFilterFunction.java).

```java
package com.dataartisans.filters;

import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader;
import com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RichFilterFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.checkpoint.CheckpointedAsynchronously;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


/**
  * This class filters duplicates that occur within a configurable time of each other in a data stream.
  */
public class DedupeFilterFunction<T, K extends Serializable> extends RichFilterFunction<T> implements CheckpointedAsynchronously<HashSet<K>> {

  private LoadingCache<K, Boolean> dedupeCache;
  private final KeySelector<T, K> keySelector;
  private final long cacheExpirationTimeMs;

  /**
    * @param cacheExpirationTimeMs The expiration time for elements in the cache
    */
  public DedupeFilterFunction(KeySelector<T, K> keySelector, long cacheExpirationTimeMs){
    this.keySelector = keySelector;
    this.cacheExpirationTimeMs = cacheExpirationTimeMs;
  }

  @Override
  public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
    createDedupeCache();
  }


  @Override
  public boolean filter(T value) throws Exception {
    K key = keySelector.getKey(value);
    boolean seen = dedupeCache.get(key);
    if (!seen) {
      dedupeCache.put(key, true);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public HashSet<K> snapshotState(long checkpointId, long checkpointTimestamp) throws Exception {
    return new HashSet<>(dedupeCache.asMap().keySet());
  }

  @Override
  public void restoreState(HashSet<K> state) throws Exception {
    createDedupeCache();
    for (K key : state) {
      dedupeCache.put(key, true);
    }
  }

  private void createDedupeCache() {
    dedupeCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
      .expireAfterWrite(cacheExpirationTimeMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .build(new CacheLoader<K, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean load(K k) throws Exception {
          return false;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Although this may be a good answer, links get broken with time and it would be good if you copy-paste at least the relevant parts of the code. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the code, i dont see any output unfortunately. when i run it, i dont see any of the text i wrote into the console (i typed nv -lk 9999 and entered in "Google 1" then "Amazon 2"). can you extend the example to print out the filtered outputs to the console please? i only see ... Source: TweetImpression Source w/ duplicates -> Filter(1/1) switched to CANCELED 
.. Co-Flat Map -> (Sink: Unnamed, Sink: Unnamed, Sink: Unnamed, Sink: Unnamed, Sink: Unnamed)(1/1) switched to CANCELED 
... Job execution switched to status RESTARTING

Comment: The output you are looking for is in the log files on the TaskManagers.  If you run this example in your IDE you should see it in the console as well.