# apache fink 0.10 Filtering duplicates over an infinite stream with time window purge

Tags: purge, flink-streaming

how can i filter out duplicates over an infinite stream with a time window purge? I dont have infinite space / ram and i know that after say, 2 seconds (on the local clock), any duplicate that can occur will have occured. which means that after 2 seconds i can throw away (purge) the old data.

Filtering duplicates over an infinite stream with time window purge.

I got an excellent answer to how to remove the duplicates here in this question (big thanks to Till): [apache flink 0.10 how to get the first occurence of a composite key from an unbounded input dataStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599069/apache-flink-0-10-how-to-get-the-first-occurence-of-a-composite-key-from-an-unbo)

but i dont know how to tell flink to throw away the old data after 2 seconds (local time).

how can i do this with flink 0.10 please?

Thanks alot!!!

here is the statement which removes duplicates but doesnt purge:

```
input.keyBy(0, 1).flatMap(new DuplicateFilter()).print();
```

if I add `.timeWindow(Time.minutes(1), Time.seconds(30))` after `keyBy(0, 1)` its not compilable.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Till - the answer is given in an update to the following link: 
[apache flink 0.10 how to get the first occurence of a composite key from an unbounded input dataStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599069/apache-flink-0-10-how-to-get-the-first-occurence-of-a-composite-key-from-an-unbo)

see the update.