# Flink 1.5 DataStream: Duplicate Filtering

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I have an unbound DataStream that represents friendship in a social network. These friendships can be bidirectional and therefore appear twice in the stream.

The structure of the data is: timestamp|user1|user2 .
For example:

```
2010-03-09T02:51:11.571+0000|143|1219
2010-03-09T06:08:51.942+0000|1242|4624
2010-03-09T08:24:03.773+0000|2191|4986
2010-03-09T09:37:09.788+0000|459|4644
```

I want to remove bidirectional friendships to count them only once. In practice I would like filter duplicates.
I have found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35600175)

My FilterFunction looks like:

```
   def filter(ds: DataStream[String]): DataStream[(String, String, String)] = {

    val res = data.
      mapWith(line => {
        val str = line.split("\\|")
        if (str(1).toLong > str(2).toLong)
          (str(0), str(1), str(2))
        else
           (str(0), str(2), str(1))
      })
       .keyBy(tuple => (tuple._2, tuple._3))
      .flatMap(new FilterFunction())

    res
  }
```

And I have implemented my RichFlatMapFunction as:

```
class FilterFunction extends RichFlatMapFunction[(String, String, String), (String, String, String)] {

  private var seen: ValueState[Boolean] = _

  override def flatMap(value: (String, String, String), out: 
Collector[(String, String, String)]): Unit = {

     if (!seen.value() || seen.value() == null) {
       seen.update(true)
       out.collect(value)
     }
   }

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
     seen = getRuntimeContext.getState(
       new ValueStateDescriptor("seen", classOf[Boolean])
     )
   }
}
```

However when i print I'm getting random results. I have tried to perform a count in a time window of 1 year:

```
val da1 = filter(data)
  .mapWith(tuple => Parser.parseUserConnection(tuple).get)
  .assignAscendingTimestamps(connection => connection.timestamp.getMillis)
  .mapWith(connection => (connection, 1))
  .timeWindowAll(Time.days(365))
  .sum(1)
  .mapWith(tuple => tuple._2)
  .print()
```

My console print the first time:

```
1> 33735
```

Then:

```
1> 10658
2> 33735
```

and for subsequent execution, different results (Just 33735 seems to be stable). I cannot understand this strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to follow what you are finding surprising. But a general technique for debugging such an app is to print the results of different stages of the pipeline to see at what point the results become strange. Or debug the job in an IDE and step through it.

Comment: Yes the problem is almost surely in the RichFlatMapFunction